# Saving image from android file system to IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, indexeddb

Some background first:

**Platform:** Android 4.4.2 with access to entire kernel source. Compiling my own Android build

**App in question:** It's strictly a webview/HTML5 application. Everything in Javascript/jQuery . Android activity just launches webview then Javascript does the rest.

**Function:** When you start the app, the platform automatically in background receives jpeg  via wifi/BT etc. HW/OS saves the image locally in Android file system say at /data/somefolder/image.jpeg

Now the webview reads this image and displays (which it can) and also needs to store in IndexedDB for caching. And that's where the problem comes.

When making `XMLHttpRequest()` to load image as per the code below:

```
var db = Database.indexedDB.tags;

// Create XHR
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(), blob;
xhr.open("GET", "file:///data/somefolder/image.jpeg", true); //I suspect I am not specifying the image correctly
// Set the responseType to blob
xhr.responseType = "blob";

xhr.addEventListener("load", function () {
  if (xhr.status === 200) {
    // Blob as response
    blob = xhr.response;
    console.log("Blob Retrieved from image URL");
    var browserName = BrowserType().brand;

    // Put the blob into the dabase
    if (browserName == 'Chrome') {
        // Chrome can't store blobs at the moment.
        // Convert to base64.
        convertToBase64(blob, continuation);
    } else {
        continuation(blob);
    }

    function continuation(blob) {
        // Open a transaction to the database
        var transaction = db.transaction(["tagStore"], 'readwrite');
        tag.blob = blob;
        var putRequest = transaction.objectStore("tagStore").put(tag, new Date().getTime());

        putRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
            console.log( "blob Stored in database!");
        };

        putRequest.onerror = function(event) {
            console.log(key + " Storage Error:" + event);
        };
    }

  }else{
    console.log("ERROR: Blob Can't Be Retrieved from URL:" + "xhr.status = "+xhr.status);
  }
}, false);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
//console.log(xhr.readyState+" " + xhr.status);
}
// Send XHR
xhr.send();
```

**Error when above code executes**

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///data/somefolder/image.jpeg Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
```

My indexedDB implementation is derived from a very good tutorial [Mozilla Hacks](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/storing-images-and-files-in-indexeddb/). and other such examples. I have made sure that it works in my other applications.

**Problem Statement:**
So, is there a way to save the image from Android file system to IndexedDB?

Thank you.

Comment: Query - if you are saving the image to the file system, why are you also saving it to IndexedDB? The file is already local, copying it to IDB won't make it any quicker.

Comment: @RaymondCamden The OS always saves current image (with same file name) and I want to be able to cache those images for later use. And also want to make this platform agnostic, the idea is to make the same Javascript work with other OS such as QNX. So, it will read the image from whatever OS and cache it in IndexedDb.